# Nested Json Object display in different dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery

On selecting JSON object from dropdown list the values releted to that object should display in body or textbox.

The Dropdown list control can be static or dynamic.

Suppose
If i select "BFS-Retails" in dropdownlist then in another dropdownlist should display "Industries","CompaniesImpacted","AverageVolatility","Others"  . when i select "Others" 
then in another dropdown list should display "FinancialIndustries" , "RegulatoryIndustries" , "MAIndustries" , "RestructuringIndustries" , "LeadershipIndustries" . When i select "Industries" then 
it should display complete values in some textbox or in body content and for all others JSON Object.

Can any one help me out with these issue using jquery
Below is my json demo .

```
    {
   "BFS-Retail":{
      "Industries":{
         "A":100,
         "B":50.8292245629763,
         "C":81.5777678171224
      },
      "CompaniesImpacted":{
         "A":62.1621621621622,
         "B":48.6486486486487,
         "C":70.2702702702703
      },
      "AverageVolatility":{
         "A":2.62162162162162,
         "B":1.7027027027027,
         "C":1.89189189189189
      },
      "Others":{
         "FinancialIndustries":{
            "A":0.200430812566127,
            "B":0.189938259829807,
            "C":0.157663896336683
         },
         "RegulatoryIndustries":{
            "A":0.296020892405356,
            "B":0.114314693416088,
            "C":0.218004399872945
         },
         "MAIndustries":{
            "A":0.493368154008927,
            "B":0.233905449605226,
            "C":0.490509899714126
         },
         "RestructuringIndustries":{
            "A":0.140301568796289,
            "B":0.0439671897754184,
            "C":0.163503299904709
         },
         "LeadershipIndustries":{
            "A":0.499535255934039,
            "B":0.246216262742343,
            "C":0.246216262742343
         }
      }
   },
   "BFS-Commercial":{
      "Industries":{
         "A":1.38065889735545,
         "B":0.30681308830121,
         "C":27.9199910354101
      },
      "CompaniesImpacted":{
         "A":15,
         "B":5,
         "C":35
      },
      "AverageVolatility":{
         "A":0.15,
         "B":0.1,
         "C":1.3
      },
      "Others":{
         "FinancialIndustries":{
            "A":0,
            "B":0,
            "C":0.0206818181818182
         },
         "RegulatoryIndustries":{
            "A":0,
            "B":0,
            "C":0.0206818181818182
         },
         "MAIndustries":{
            "A":0.0045,
            "B":0.0025,
            "C":0.144772727272727
         },
         "RestructuringIndustries":{
            "A":0,
            "B":0.0025,
            "C":0.124090909090909
         },
         "LeadershipIndustries":{
            "A":0.018,
            "B":0,
            "C":0.144772727272727
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you found out so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: how are you creating your dropdowns from the json object?

Comment: You need to create dropdowns dynamically based on levels in your dropdown.

Comment: @felix Hi, i want implement display these nested JSON object using 2 or 3 dropdown list . Based on selected items i want to display json values

Comment: I understand that. But what *exactly* do you have problems with? Where are you stuck? I mean, you must have tried *something*. Do you know how to parse JSON? Do you know how to iterate over the properties of an object? How to use recursion? How to create DOM elements? How to populate a `<select>` element with `<option>`s? How to bind event handlers? There many pieces to that problem and you have to tell us what exactly you are having problems with.

Comment: By using static dropdown control

Comment: Here is the code what i have tried http://jsfiddle.net/07fgpw9e/6/

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add the relevant code and explain the problem you have with it.

Comment: @FelixKling I have updated the Question . Let me know if there is any further changes required

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic dynamic options generation code same process can be used to generate dropdown for others selection also

```
var firstSelect = $('<select id="firstSelect"></select>');
var secondSelect = $('<select id="secondSelect"> </select>');
$.each(data, function(item, key) {
    firstSelect.append('<option >' + item + '</option>');
});
$("#container").html(firstSelect);
$("#firstSelect").on("change", function(e) {
    var item;
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected === "BFS-Retail") {
        item = data[selected];
    } else {
        item = data[selected];
    }
    $(secondSelect).html('');
    $.each(item, function(item, key) {
        secondSelect.append('<option >' + item + '</option>');
    });
});

$("#container").append(secondSelect);
```

fiddle link::
http://jsfiddle.net/036easd8/1/

Comment: Thanks Surz, Could you tell me if I select "Others" from 2nd dropdownlist then in 3rd dropdown list should display "FinancialIndustries" , " RegulatoryIndustries" etc.. And also how to display the values with respect to selected object.