# how to populate two <selects> via ajax with a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am making a system and I came across the following doubt .. I have two  being the first to select the brand of the vehicle and the second would be to select the model of the vehicle. but I would like to select the brand of the vehicle and the  of the model to load the models of the vehicles for the selected brand.

i have onde archive .json with brand and models of cars.
exemple format json

```
"value":"ACURA","title":"Acura","models":[{"value":"CL_MODELS","title":"CL Models (4)"}]}


<select id="brand"></select>
<select id="models"></select>
```

so I populate the first  with the tags so the second  would be populated with the models referring to the selected brand.

I need it when I select, for example BMW, the second  select only the models referring to BMW, and not all models.

How do you do this?

thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Json Object display in different dropdownlist using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904659/nested-json-object-display-in-different-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about how the data is being fetched, but I believe you're asking about manipulating it in a way that makes it usable by the 2 selects. Take a look at the example below:

```js
var json = [{
    "value": "ACURA",
    "title": "Acura",
    "models": [{
      "value": "CL_MODELS",
      "title": "CL Models (4)"
    }]
  },
  {
    "value": "TOYOTA",
    "title": "Toyota",
    "models": [{
      "value": "TOYOTA_MODELS",
      "title": "Toyota Models (4)"
    }]
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#models').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#brand')
    .append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", "")
    .text(""));
  $.each(json, function(index) {
    $('#brand')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", json[index]["value"])
        .text(json[index]["title"]));
  });
  $('#brand').change(function() {
    process($(this).children(":selected").html());
  });
});

function process(brand) {
  $('#models').prop('disabled', false).find('option')
    .remove()
    .end();

  var models = $.map(json, function(entry) {
    if (entry["title"] === brand) {
      return entry["models"];
    }
  });
  $.each(models, function(index) {
    $('#models')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", models[index]["value"])
        .text(models[index]["title"]));
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brand"></select>
<select id="models"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//YOUR_JSON_DATA
//{"value":"ACURA","title":"Acura","models":[{"value":"CL_MODELS","title":"CL Models (4)"}]}


$.get( YOUR_JSON_DATA, function( data ) {
  // Did you want data to be an array of brands?
  for (let brand of data) {
    $("#brand").append(`<option>${ brand.value }</option>`)
    for (let models of brand.models) {
      $("#models").append(`<option> ${ models.value } </option>`)
    }
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="brand"></select>
<select id="models"></select>
```

Here is an example code snippet for ya.  I hope it provides some clarity.  Did you want the JSON data be an array?

Comment: "Did you want data to be an array of brands?" yes 72 brands and more 1300 models

Comment: yes it was clear but I need it when I select, for example BMW, the second <select> select only the models referring to BMW, and not all models, yes would be a array